# jQuery load finish-event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want to expand a division with data that should be loaded from another server.

the problem is if i start expanding the division (toggleslide) and the load method finishs the height is jumping and the effect is destroyed.

what i want is that jquery starts expanding AFTER the data-transfer finished but my following code does not work:

```
// divison name = details
details.load("index.php", expandLastResultDetails3(details));

function expandLastResultDetails3(details) {
    $(details).slideToggle('slow', function () {
        ready();
    });
}
```

the box is jumping because (i guess) the slidetoggle starts to early.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) expects a *function* callback to be called upon the completion of the request. However, instead of passing a callback, you are **executing** the function. Try the following:

```
details.load("index.php", function () {
  expandLastResultDetails3(details);
});
```